# How to paste in a sheet "Evaluate Formula" steps?

Tags: excel, vba, array-formulas

I'd like to know is someone knows by VBA can be accessed the content of built-in "Evaluate Formula" tool? to be able to see understand better each step of how it works a formula, since the Evaluate Formula window is too small and for array formulas, that handle many values, is needed to scroll down/up.

Maybe a way to take like screenshots or the text (like when pressed F9) of each evaluation steps from Evaluate Formula Window and paste them ordered in another sheet.

[image]

I'm tested some apps (like [this one](https://ewbi.blogs.com/develops/2004/12/excel_formula_p.html)) that breaks in parts/parse the formulas but doesn't evaluates the steps.

Comment: Take each step and make them individual formula.  Then you can see the output of each step.

Comment: Yes. That is the only time consuming way I know now. Due to that I ask if there is a programmatically way to do it.